# Passing multiple arguments in Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments

The following code passes a list (varbinds) and it works fine.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = Main2_TrapToTxtDb, args = (varBinds,))
```

Now I need to pass **another  variable - vString** along with this.

Please help with a simple code.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: t1 = threading.Thread(target = Main2_TrapToTxtDb, args = (varBinds,)).... all I know.   Google search showed up kwargs, seems difficult to grasp.

Comment: `args = (varBinds,vString)`

Comment: thanx, if varbinds is a list, then what is the syntax - args = ((varBinds),vString) ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `args` parameter is a tuple, and allows you to pass many arguments to the target.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=Main2_TrapToTxtDb, args=(varBinds, otherVariable))
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

> threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
> kwargs={})
>
> This constructor should always be called with keyword arguments. Arguments are:
>
> group should be None; reserved for future extension when a ThreadGroup class is implemented.
>
> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.
>
> name is the thread name. By default, a unique name is constructed of the form “Thread-N” where N is a small decimal number.
>
> args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ().
>
> kwargs is a dictionary of keyword arguments for the target invocation. Defaults to {}.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the varbinds is a list. So the comma after the variable inside parenthesis...(varBinds,). So what is the syntax to add additional variables be added after a list variable. I feel confused.

Comment: @Manmathan I think you are not sure what you are doing. `varBinds` is a list, so? Is it a list of arguments? Is it an argument whose type is `list`? Do you want to pass a list of arguments which contains `vString`? If so, just append it to `varBinds`.

Comment: @Manmathan I presume you added that comma because you got an error and noticed that comma got you rid of it. The `args` parameter receives a `tuple`, but when you have only one argument, you cannot write `(argument)`, because this is parsed as `argument`, which is not a tuple. Therefore, you have to put a comma, so it is interpreted as a tuple: `(argument, )`. Since this tuple is meant to contain the arguments you pass to the thread's function, just put all the arguments in the tuple, as I wrote in the answer: `(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`.

Comment: @Manmathan It seems your list is actually an argument of type `list`. Therefore, just write (once again, as I wrote in my answer): `args=(varBinds, vString)` (BTW, here the comma is optional, because there are two elements in the tuple, so Python interprets this unambiguously).

Comment: @Manmathan You're welcome, but think about the documentation next time ;)